# ERROR Code=-4220 and SQLSTATE= null

Tags: java, jdbc, exception, db2

I am using db2 version 10.5 and inserting the values into the DB2JSON, created a simple standalone java program to retrieve all the values from the table(Collection) when I run the query I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.69.66] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBObjectRowHandler.handle(DBObjectRowHandler.java:38)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBObjectRowHandler.handle(DBObjectRowHandler.java:14)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.BaseResultIterator.next(BaseResultIterator.java:119)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBCursor.fetchResultsEagerly(DBCursor.java:801)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBCursor.find(DBCursor.java:895)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:278)
      at com.ws.Demo.TestingDemo.main(TestingDemo.java:47)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.69.66] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:733)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:66)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:120)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kc.a(kc.java:2868)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kc.p(kc.java:525)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kc.Z(kc.java:2747)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getObjectX(ResultSet.java:1438)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getObject(ResultSet.java:1413)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBResultSet.getObject(DBResultSet.java:255)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBData.getObjectX(DBData.java:66)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBObjectRowHandler.getObjectID(DBObjectRowHandler.java:58)
      at com.ibm.nosql.json.api.DBObjectRowHandler.handle(DBObjectRowHandler.java:28)
      ... 6 more
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 290
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.r.a(r.java:19)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kc.a(kc.java:2864)
      ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.io.MalformedInputException
      at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(ByteToCharUTF8.java:292)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.r.a(r.java:16)
      ... 15 more
```

I also went throught few posts where it suggest to use db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3 but I have no idea where to use it, and also I few other posts it is suggested touse the lastest version db2jcc.jar, I am using the jars that is present inside the db2 10.5 under sqllib folder. Anyone let me know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the charset decoder encoder using system property inside your Java code.

For example:

```
System.setProperty("db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder", "3");
```

Comment: i tried DB db = NoSQLClient.getDB(databaseUrl, user, password, ns);
            DBCollection col = db.getCollection("******");
            System.setProperty("db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder","3");
            BasicDBObject db1 = new BasicDBObject();
            DBCursor cursor = col.find();

Comment: and still getting the same error. am i doing it right?

Comment: @raghulc `System.setProperty("db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder","3");` should be first line of your class but you are setting the property after getting the connection.

Comment: Oh my bad let me try that

Comment: yes. now i am not getting the error. Only because of special characters that can be present in  my db i need to use the code that you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, if it meets your requirement

Comment: i would like to know if there are any other situation when we need to give this

Answer (score 3):

Add the following environment variable(Java VM arguments) in your tomcat settings

-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3

This worked.